# Jenkinsfile how to iterate through subfolder/subfile names?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Suppose my directory is like this:

```
Project
|
|
| -- Jenkinsfile
|
| -- SubFolder1
|
| -- SubFolder2
```

I am using a script version of `Jenkinsfile`. I am wondering, how can I iterate through `Project` and get all folder names as one string?

If I do something like:

```
def filenames = [];
    def dir = new File("$PWD");
    dir.traverse(type: FILES, maxDepth: 0) {
        filenames.add(it.getName())
    }
```

It doesn't work since `$PWD` doesnt seem to be the actual current `Project/` directory. Thanks!

Comment: The `File` class will only find paths on the Jenkins master, and not on the build agents. Also, a shell interpreter environment variable will not resolve in a Groovy interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

`${WORKSPACE}` will point to the current running job local file system path.

See: http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html/ for environment variables list

Change localhost and port to your Jenkins instance.